# How to configure reconnect to Kafka in Spring-Cloud-Stream

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I have developed a simple Kafka consumer with spring-cloud-stream which works just fine. When Kafka is shut down the framework even performs an automatic reconnect. The problem is that the reconnect is attempted at full speed (on my machine about 10 times per second).

Question: how can I configure the reconnect behavior in terms of interval between two attempts, backoff etc?

**Update**
As Marius suggested I opened an Issue. I take this as a hint that my desired feature does not exist. Thank you for the answer!

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/541

Answer (score 1):

Please open a github issue. The properties mentioned are indeed for retrying in case of an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can control them via per channel binding consumer properties (maxAttempts, backOffInitialInterval, backOffMaxInterval, backOffMultiplier) with the prefix:

`spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<channelName>.consumer.`

Comment: I know these properties, but there is none like the ones I asked for. They are for controlling redelivery of messages.